# Не могу определить расширение файла: AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'suffix'

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Как заставить данный код работать?

```
self.fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()[0]
f = open(self.fname, 'r')
if self.fname.suffix == '.py':
     self.strList = ['if', 'print','else', 'elif','def','self','for','while','with','or']
```

Получают данную ошибку:

```
 AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'suffix'
```

Comment: приведённый код не должен подобную ошибку вызывать (`QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()[0]` это строка, а не файловый объект)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте библиотеку `pathlib`  и функцию [`PurePosixPath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.suffix)

```
import sys
from pathlib import PurePosixPath
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushBotton, QVBoxLayout, QFileDialog


class Test(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        button = QPushButton('нажми')
        button.clicked.connect(self.a)
        lay = QVBoxLayout()
        lay.addWidget(button)
        self.setLayout(lay)

    def a(self):
        self.fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()[0]
        if PurePosixPath(self.fname).suffix == '.py':
            print('next')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Test()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```